# Can I output arbitrary HTML code while converting LaTeX to HTML using make4ht?

Tags: tex4ht, html, htlatex, make4ht

My code:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\world}{world}
\begin{document}
hello \world{}
\end{document}
```

I compile this with `make4ht` like this:

```
$ make4ht foo.tex        
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
[STATUS]  make4ht: Input file: foo.tex
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion finished
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xml:lang='en-US' lang='en-US'> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta name='generator' content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' /> 
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' /> 
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='foo.css' /> 
<meta name='src' content='foo.tex' /> 
</head><body>
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='noindent'>hello world </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Can I tell `make4ht` or `tex4ht` or `htlatex` to output raw HTML at some places I need? For example, I want that whenever I invoke the new command `\world`, it is wrapped with `<span>` tag around it like this: `<span class="keyword">world</span>`.

In other words whatever currently appears as merely `world` in the HTML output should appear as `<span class="keyword">world</span>` in the HTML output. Can this be done? If yes, can you please provide a minimal working code that shows how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine your `\world` command in a custom `.cfg` file. Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
% save original contents of the \world macro
\let\orig@world\world
\renewcommand\world{\HCode{<span class="keyword">}\orig@world\HCode{</span>}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

We save the original `\world` macro in `\orig@world`. This way, you can stay synchronized with your LaTeX file, and when you decide that `\world` should produce something different than string "world", you don't need to change this configuration. You can then redefine `\world` to use `\HCode` commands to insert the HTML code, and the saved `\orig@world` to produce the "world" text.

compile using:

```
make4ht -c config.cfg samle.tex
```

This is the result:

```html
 <p class='noindent'>hello <span class='keyword'>world</span> </p>
```